# What is the equivalent of this code in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

```
OleDbConnection con;
OleDbDataReader read;
OleDbCommand cmd;

private void btn_clicked(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    con = new OleDbConnection(WindowsFormsApplication2.Properties.Settings.Default.DBConString);
    con.Open();

    cmd = new OleDbCommand( " SELECT * FROM tbPeople WHERE country = ' " textbox.Text " ' ", con );

    read = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    while(read.Read())
    {
        textboxTest.text += read["lastname"].toString() +  ", " + read["firstname"].toString() + "\n";
    }
}
```

I'm new to Entity Framework, and I would like this code to be converted.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have already created edmx data model and have data context as `dbContext`, your equivalent query will look like somewhat :

```
var country=textbox.text;
var peoples=dbContext.tbPeople.where(c=>c.country==country).ToList()

foreach(var people in peoples)
{
   textboxTest.text += people.lastname  +  ", " + people.firstname + "\n";
}
```

Comment: cool :) also there are many good msdn samples to refer if you just started with entity framework. thx!!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming when you create your entities you don't prefix with tb and also use normal casing

```
using(var db = new MyAwesomeContext())
{
    var names = db.People.Where(x => x.Country == textbox.Text)
                         .Select(x => $"{x.LastName}, {x.FirstName}")
                         .ToList();

    textboxTest.text = string.Join("\n", names);
}
```

---

**Additional Resources**

[Enumerable.Where Method (IEnumerable, Func)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Filters a sequence of values based on a predicate.

[Enumerable.Select Method (IEnumerable, Func)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Projects each element of a sequence into a new form.

[String.Join Method (String, String[])](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Concatenates all the elements of a string array, using the specified
>   separator between each element.